# Group cell rows in FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I want rows of cells in FPDF to be a group, so that the group of cells would move to the next page after a page break. How to do it in FPDF?

Example of normal output:

```
Cell 1 | Cell 2 //first row
--------page break------------
Cell 3 | Cell 4 //second row
```

My wanted output is:

```
--------page break------------
Cell 1 | Cell 2 //first row
Cell 3 | Cell 4 //second row
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. It'd be very helpful if you could expand your question with a code sample of your best effort to solve the problem so far.

Comment: Before putting the first row, check the current position on the page. If it's too low, add an explicit page break first.